# How to lock redis write and release using stackexchange redir?

Tags: c#, .net, redis

I want to update the redis item using lock.

```
 public void Write(CacheItem item){
        if (_database.LockTake("worker", "token", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)))
        {
            try
            {
                var cache = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
                _database.StringSet("worker", cache, TimeSpan.MaxValue);
            }
            finally
            {
                _database.LockRelease("worker", "token");
            }
        }
 }
```

CacheItem includes counter. multiple worker thread gets value of redis CacheItem,  and update the counter. If a worker gets the item, it will update and other can access source and update it. otherwise two or mode worker gets counter as 0 and increase it and all and saves as 1. But itshould be 3.

How can I do this?